# Scraping data from a dictionary using vba

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape some data from a dictionary with a condition and print the result data to my excel document.

The Website: https://tureng.com/tr/turkce-ingilizce

Excel Document Sample

[image]

The code needs to take the data from column (A) and print it to the searchbar on the website. Then it needs to click enter and take the translated data whose type matches the column (E) which is in my document. For example: adjective means "s." on the website. So the code should take the first word that has "s." for the example word "all right"

As a result of my tryings, I came to this stage, but I do not know how to pull data of class type depending on the condition. Can you guys please help me?

```
Const URLstr As String = "https://tureng.com/tr/turkce-ingilizce/seal"

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim ieDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Dim searchfield As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim searchbutton As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim result As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement


Dim i As Integer

Set objIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

objIE.Navigate URLstr
Do Until objIE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop

Set ieDoc = objIE.document
objIE.Visible = True
                   
            For i = 2 To 94
                Set searchfield = ieDoc.all.Item("searchTerm")
                Application.Wait Now() + #12:00:01 AM#
                searchfield.Value = Cells(i, 1)
                searchfield.Select
                
                Application.SendKeys "~"
                
                
                Application.Wait Now() + #12:00:01 AM#

                    
                
                Set result = ieDoc.all.Item("tr ts")(0)
                    Cells(i, 2) = result.innerText
            Next i
           
        objIE.Quit

End Sub
```

html code of the website

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("en tm")`

Comment: I have tried and I did not get what ı want. Maybe the syntax was not correct. But what about the condition?

Comment: You can try getting the full text into a string (strMyHtml=ieDoc.documentElement.outerHTML) and use string functions to search : like  instr(strMyHtml, "tr ts"), and use mid to extract. I will look into why the getElement is not working, iyi sanslar

Comment: tried this: Dim oElement As Object
                For Each oElement In ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("tr ts")
                    Debug.Print oElement.innerHTML
                Next oElement
There are lots of those...